# How do i access files in a large directory with subfolders without knowing in advance how many folders are in the large directory in android kotlin?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

[image]

I have a path to a large directory, and I want to get all the files to that directory. I have a function that after returning all files and folders in a directory (including the path of the file and the subdirectory), I use RxJava recursive algorithm to get the files in the directory big, however this is not being successful. I need help

```
private fun getAllFileInFolderNew() {
    val disposable = phoneStorageManager.getAllExternalFile(rootFolder.path, rootFolder.storage!!)
            .delay(DELAY_GET_DATA, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .flatMap {
                if (it.value?.size == 0) {
                    return@flatMap Observable.empty()
                }
                return@flatMap Observable.fromIterable(it.value) }//Sort
            .flatMap {
                return@flatMap getNumItemInFolder(it) //Get the folder capacity
            }
            .subscribe({
                fileList.add(it) //add in list
            }
            })


private fun getSizeFolder(fileData: FileData): Observable<FileData>{
    return phoneStorageManager.getAllExternalFile(fileData.path, fileData.storage!!)
            .delay(DELAY_GET_DATA, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .map {
                it.value?.filter { it.isDir == true }
                ?????
            }
}
```

Comment: Then what is the problem exactly? You let us guess now. What is not successfull?

Comment: `How do i access files in a large directory with subfolders...` It looks more to me that you are trying to list those files only.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this , this in java but it work the same in kotlin :

First create a list "lets say filesList" of files as global variable , and then call recursive method that take the top parent folder as parameter to list all files in that directory .

```
    private void getMyFiles(File dir) {
        File files[] = dir.listFiles();
        if (files!=null){
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    getMyFiles(file);
                } else {
                    filesList.add(file);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```